# LinkedIn connection search by first name and last name

Tags: api, linkedin-api

Is there way to search first name and last name for linkedin connection filter using LinkedIn API?

Suppose I am authenticated by linkedIn and show connection in popup.LinkedIn connection response only 500 connection one time request. So I do paging 500 connection. But I want to send invitations to two persons, so I want to give search widget by first name and last name from my LinkedIn connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [People Search API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api) to search on first and last name, restricting the search to just your connections:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?first-name=Clair&last-name=Smith&facet=network,F
```

**Update:**

In terms of 'filtering' the returned values to remove the current user making the call from the result set, you should check for the returned user's relationship to the viewer:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,relation-to-viewer:(distance)))?first-name=Clair&last-name=Smith&facet=network,F
```

Then check the results, and remove the users that have a `relation-to-user` of 0.

Comment: Using people search API we can search by firstname and lastname .But when i add facet=network,F parameter restricting search in my connection then i get error "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized"

Comment: [link] http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?Keywords="Clair%smith" . I am not exactly know user enter firstname or lastname or both in search textbox so i am using "keywords"? but my problem is that the "keywords" searches all profile selector fields in linkedin profile i want to restrict it searches only first name or last name or both in linkedin profile? how to do it

Comment: @sunil It's one or the other - `keywords` searches all fields, `first-name` and `last-name` search just what you'd expect.

Comment: In my application there is textbox so user can enter first-name or last-name or both how i find out it is first-name or last-name or full name. so i am using "Keywords" and restrict it searches only first_name and last_name in linked in profile and give me proper result through "People Search API " ? What parameter send to search People API parameter it searches only first name and lastname using Parameter "Keywords"

Comment: @sunil the parameter to tell the People Search API to only search first name is just that, `first-name`. In terms of your UI, why not just show the user a separate box for first name, one for last name so you can send those values right to the API? This is exactly what LinkedIn does on their own webpage.

Comment: Paul  :- when we search using people search API with parameter &facet=network,F then we got 1st connection.But issue is that in 1st connection owner Linkedin account name is display.How to exclude this owner account name from search result from first connection.For example i have 18 connection when using Connection API but when i using people search api and Facet=Network,F then it returns 19 connection including owner account name.

Comment: @sunil I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say one of the connections returned has 'LinkedIn owner account name' displayed. Do you mean that one of the results, instead of name just says "LinkedIn Account" or something similar?

Comment: Paul:-suppose i login sunil patil using linkedin account the first connections include owner name "sunil patil" as connection in connection result set.

Comment: @sunil Added content to answer to determine which user's to filter.

Comment: @PaulMennega Is it possible to search by company and keyword in my connection search?